# How to get the key from a nested map (JSON) using given value in Groovy in JIRA Scriptrunner

Tags: groovy, jira

Hope this question finds you all in good health.

As per title, would like to know how this is done in Groovy. Found a few, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60212942/getting-value-from-nested-map-in-groovy-using-a-nested-key), but the question and answer did not help.

The JSON is like this

```
def ​json = '''{
     "boston": [
{
  "name":"bob",
  "phone":"242 123123",
},
{
  "name":"alice",
  "phone":"212-123-345",
}
],
"chicago": [
{
  "name":"charlie",
  "phone":"313-232-545",
},
{
  "name":"denise",
  "phone":"414-123-546",
}
]
}'''
```

But how do I use the value, for example **bob** to get `boston`?

When you use `parsedjson['chicago']['email']`, the result would be

```
[charlie@chicago.com, denise@chicago.com]
```

I tried to do something like

```
def getKey = parsedjson['email']?.key
```

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14044614/finding-the-key-in-a-map-given-the-value) but in JIRA ScriptRunner console returned `null`

Any pointer is greatly appreciated in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parsedjson['email']?.key` returned `null` because `key` is not a `List` method. `key` is an [`Entry`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#find(groovy.lang.Closure)) method so to find the key from a value you have to iterate through the Map's Entry Set.

Here's an example to get the city from the person's name using [`Map.find`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#find(groovy.lang.Closure)) which returns an `Entry`:

```
parsedjson.find { it.value.find { it["name"] == "bob" } }.key
```